# Add data to object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know I can do something like that:

```
var data = [
    {
        name: 'test1',
        value: 1
    }
];
```

But I want to fill `data` with dynamic values (from HTML). So I will have `var data = [];` and how can I fill this one? I know, it must be somewhere on the internet, but I don not know the "right words" to search.

Note: `data` have to be array filled with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, like so

```js
var data = [];

data.push({ name: 'test1',  value: 1});
data.push({ name: 'test2',  value: 2});
data.push({ name: 'test3',  value: 3});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'push' method.

```js
var a = [];

a.push({item: 'a', value : 'a'});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: In your example there is error, you can not use = in object literal

Comment: When I saw your answers, I already realised that .push method, applied and worked well, so first time I did not see that `=`.